# How to remove a commit which does not show with 'git rebase'?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a repository with only one branch named `main`.

Here is what `git log --oneline --graph --all` outputs:

```sh
* 92033fe (HEAD -> main, origin/main) [test] Add some new tests
* 5e281c4 [style] Improve code formatting
* 50ccf6a release-1
| * 307cfba (tag: 1.0.0) release-1
|/
* 7d734b4 [feat] Add new feature
* 0b3c993 [fix] Fix some tests
```

What happened here is that I tried to tag, after the fact, commit `50ccf6a` as `1.0.0`, but did something wrong, and now I have this duplicated, and seemingly branching out, commit `307cfba`, which I want to get rid of, without affecting the rest of the branch.

Usually, I do `git rebase -i --root main`, but this particular commit does not appear in the list of commits, only those I intend to keep:

```sh
pick 0b3c993 [fix] [fix] Fix some tests
pick 7d734b4 [feat] Add new feature
pick 50ccf6a release-1
pick 5e281c4 [style] Improve code formatting
pick 92033fe [test] Add some new tests
```

What is happening here?

Comment: I'm not sure how you've created a duplicate of `50ccfba`, but one option is that you can checkout `307cfba` and then run the rebase command from there. In the interactive rebase you can drop `307cfba`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commit `307cfba` is not on branch `main`.  If you want it off of branch `main`, that's easy: do nothing at all, as it's already not there.

Commit `307cfba` is found because of tag `1.0.0`.  If you want to not see `307cfba` *at all*, even with `git log --all`, you'll need to delete tag `1.0.0` (or forcibly move it, but if you intend to do that, one easy way is to delete it first, then create it again).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `--onto` option of rebase command (Try these steps on a copy of your repo to be safe).
Delete your tag first and recreate it on desired commit.

```
git tag -d 1.0.0
git tag -a 1.0.0 50ccf6a
```

```
git rebase --onto 7d734b4 50ccf6a~1
```